# no man pages on kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, manpage

I have just installed kubuntu 18.04 and I have no man pages.  I have tried all the different permutations of mandb to update the database, but I am always presented with a blank page.
Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: No manpages != man showing blank page. For some particular manpage, say `less`, what does `man -w less` output? If it shows a file path, is that file non-empty? Does `env -i TERM=$TERM /usr/bin/man less` show the manpage?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If you did, please post the solution as an answer. It may help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else interested, I was having this same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate devices. I tried reinstalling mandb, groff, and manpages, but none of these worked. However, when I tried `env -i TERM=$TERM /usr/bin/man <command>` (like @muru suggested) the manual pages appeared. I then modified my /.bashrc with an alias to this command. While it's not a cure to the problem, it is an acceptable workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a clarification and expansion:

No man pages in Kubuntu-18.04 != no man pages in the system. I too rely on Konqueror to read man (and info) pages. I especially appreciate the ability to go into finer detail on ancillary pages by right-clicking to open in a new tab or window. e.g. from the lvm manpage open new elements for pvcreate, vgcreate and lvcreate, and be able to quickly switch back and forth. I find reading man (and info) pages in Konqueror to be much more flexible and useful than on a terminal window (konsole) or the K Help Center.

At least on my system, I have no trouble issuing a "man *whatever*" command from the command line and opening up a man page, I just can't do it from within Konqueror.

Curiously, the Konqueror kio-slave for the man pages starts to work. If I enter "man:" into the URL field, it show all of the sections where the pages may be loaded; from man:/(0)/ to man:/(l)/ [that's a lower case L, not a one]. But that's as far as it will go. In the past, I could enter "man:ls" and the ls manpage would pop up. Now there's just a blank page.

Searching through the system, I find the kio-slaves for the man and info pages, but I can't find any of the kio-slaves for compression. According to https://docs.kde.org, there are kio-slaves for xz/lzma, bzip/bzip2 and gzip, but I can't find any of them on my system, nor can I figure out which packages is supposed to have them.

My guess is that since all of the manpages are gzipped, Konqueror can't display them since the gzip kio-slave isn't present on the system.

I have a backup of Kubuntu 16.04 which I made just before upgrading to 18.04. If I can't find the compression kio-slaves for Kubuntu 18.04, I may revert back to 16.04 and do some experimentation there to see if my suspicion is correct.

If someone knows which package contains the compression kio-slaves, please let me know.

Thanks,
ron